# Group orders by date

Tags: sql

I have this table food_order which contains data like:

```
ID  food_name   order_id    order_month
1   apple       123         2017-02
2   apple       345         2017-11
3   pear        4656        2017-02
4   orange      5778        2017-09
5   apple       454         2017-02
```

What I need to have is a table that shows the number of orders for a specific food in a specific month.
I.e

```
ID food name nr_orders month
1   apple   2           2017-02
```

I need to do this using joins and no other functions over there.
Help would be appreciated

Comment: what did you already try ?

Comment: Your sample data has two apple orders for that month. How come you want 10 as result?

Comment: @TemaniAfif to be honest it took me a lot of work to come to this table above, i just put it into a simpler version. I know I could achieve it with a left join but I just need a hint

Comment: @jarlh sorry,  typo, fixed

Comment: Use `count` and `group by`

Comment: What do you mean using joins and no other functions? You will need to use aggregate functions as mentioned by @anon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you could try `SQL` Query for Microsoft `SQL Server` :

```
SELECT MIN(id) [ID],
   food_name [food name],
   COUNT(order_id) [nr_orders],
   order_month
FROM #TM
GROUP BY food_name,
         order_month
ORDER BY ID;
```

Result :

```
    ID  food name   nr_orders   order_month
    1   apple       2           2017-02
    2   apple       1           2017-11
    3   pear        1           2017-02
    4   orange      1           2017-09
```

Note : order_month datatype is `VARCHAR`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
SELECT food_name, SUM(quantity) as quantity, SUM(amount) as amount, MONTH(date) as Month
FROM food_order
GROUP BY food_name, MONTH(date)
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms it is for.